# jQuery blur div not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, blur

EDIT: You can see my code working here: unf.edu/~n00804716/site/work.html

I am attempting to blur a section with jQuery when I open an iframe. The iframe is initially hidden, but appears as a fixed element above everything when a button is clicked. I have found one way to do this, but it requires an excessive amount of code. So, I tried to cut down a little, but can't get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
$('#slides iframe').hide();

$("span").click(function() {
    $("#slides iframe").fadeIn(300);
});

$('#slides iframe').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).css('display') == 'block')
    {
        $("section").css({
            'filter': 'blur(15px) greyscale(80%)'
        });
    } else {
        $("section").css({
            'filter': 'blur(0px) greyscale(0%)'
        });
    }
});
```

This is how my HTML is setup:

```
<div id="slides">
   <div id="slide-2" class="slide">
      <iframe class="zoo-video"></iframe>
      <section>
          <span></span>
          /*other content*/
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slides iframe {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
}

#slides,
section {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure if the vendor prefixes are necessary. Is there a much simpler way to do this? The trick is, the iframe is a vimeo player that takes up 90% of the screen. So, I also need the iframe to close/collapse when the page is scrolled vertically or if the user clicks outside of the iframe. When it collapses, I need it the section to no longer have a blur or grayscale. Here is the code I'm using to collapse the iframe when the user clicks outside of it:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#slides iframe");
    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.fadeOut(230);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Would you mind explaining the problem? Also check the console and make sure there aren't any errors.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The problem is that the first code block in my question above does not work. The iframe is hidden with jQuery .hide function. When I click a button that fires .fadeIn, the iframe does appear, but the section behind the iframe does not blur. Is my way of doing it above proper? Or is there a much easier way of blurring all content behind the iframe? I'm not that experienced with js or jQuery, I'm a designer, so I'm learning as I go along.

Comment: Your code isn't really good, but I think I understand what you are trying to do. *However*, the question is what your HTML looks like. The video can't be a descendant of the section you are trying to blur, or you'll have to change your code drastically. Why, you ask? Because `filter` influences the element and everything inside it. So if you try to blur the section, you'll also blur the video. Please show us the HTML you are trying to use.

Comment: @BramVanroy I've included my HTML. As you can see, the iframe is not a descendant of the section.

Comment: @BramVanroy I didn't think the code was written very well. This is my first attempt at working with CSS filters to blur elements. And my if else statements are shaky at best, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: The code isn't bad at all actually, I was wrong early on. Let me take a look and I'll get back at you. :-)

Comment: @BramVanroy Thank you very much!

Comment: Can include `css` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I've included the CSS. It's pretty simple, as you can see, the iframe is placed above the section when it appears. Nothing tricky.

Comment: You can see my code in effect here, I've uploaded it to my server: http://www.unf.edu/~n00804716/site/work.html

Comment: Can you use a modal with iframe as the content of the modal ?

Comment: @ODelibalta I could do that. Would that make it easier to blur the section below?

Comment: Sorry I have not looked at your code to be honest but it reads like you are trying to do this http://jsfiddle.net/7L5jG/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/721nma0g/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var video = $("#slides iframe");
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (!video.is(e.target) && !video.has(e.target).length) {
            video.removeClass("visible-video");
        }
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        video.addClass("visible-video");
    });
});
```

Instead of doing so much with jQuery, I often just use JS to set a class. You can do so much more with CSS than you'd think. Of importance is the CSS. You had a small spelling error (US vs UK spelling) `greyscale` vs `grayscale`. But as you can see the `+` selector is very useful here! Select the element following `.visible-video` and you can target the section that you want!

```
iframe {
    display: none; /* Hide the video initially */
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto 5%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 48px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.72), 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
}

.visible-video {
    display: block; /* show the video when the class has been set */
}
section {
    margin: 24px auto;
    width: 80%;
}
.visible-video + section {
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px) grayscale(80%);
    filter: blur(15px) grayscale(80%);
}
```

---

EDIT: I improved the CSS code of the iframe, so it'll scale better, and I included some JS that will detect if the user has clicked on the scrollbar or not. Without this addition, the iframe will also close when clicking the scrollbar.

Full screen result here: https://jsfiddle.net/721nma0g/5/embedded/result/

Edited jQuery:

```
if (!video.is(e.target) && !video.has(e.target).length && (e.target != $('html').get(0))) {
    video.removeClass("visible-video");
}
```

Edited CSS:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
    max-width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72), 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
}
```

Works great on mobile too.

[image: mobile result]

Comment: Would be a good idea to provide the CSS, despite it being obvious to experienced developers, not everyone is going to 'get it'

Comment: Thank you! This clearly cuts down on so much code. Sometimes I don't think this way to use JS to addClass, and automatically attempt to get things done with jQuery. This is a great solution. I appreciate the help greatly.

Comment: @AustinBranham I know the feeling, just keep this in mind: anything visual that can be accomplished with CSS should be accomplished with CSS, not only for performance improvement, but it also frees you to use Javascript for what it needs to be used for

Comment: @AustinBranham I used to be in the same boat, but after a while you start to think about all the downsides of jQuery. You have to load quite a big library, sometimes for just the smallest things. jQuery animations are *not* CSS animations and thus not hardware accelerated either. So I decided to go to a more basic approach. In my projects I often use vanilla JS only to add and remove classes. This saves me the bandwidth of loading jQuery, and gives me better control over the animations.

Comment: @AustinBranham I improved the code, please see the edit and the fullscreen example.